# URL returns encoded value when parsed

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am using Mechanize to open an URL and I'm parsing it with BeautifulSoup.

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
url = ('xyz.html')
br.open(url)
print br.response().read() #prints four special characters
soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read()) 
print soup #prints encoded data
```

This problem doesn't occur if I copy the HTML file locally and then parse it.

Should I decode/encode once I retrieve it through mechanize? If so, how should I do it?

Comment: Try either of these - `print str(soup)` or `print unicode(soup)`

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha No luck. Both of them still return unreadable data.